# Add column of button in asp gridview by datatable in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview, datatable

I want to add button in asp gridview by datatable in asp.net

Here is my gridview code,

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gv_productdetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <columns>                        
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MortageID" HeaderText="Id"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" />           
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now, this gridview is bind by ajax method. Here is the code,

```
//Fill Product Grid
function FillProductGrid() {            

    //Display Product
    var AcNo = document.getElementById('<%= txt_acno.ClientID%>').value;    
    var Data = JSON.stringify({ mortgageNo: MortgageNo, acNo: AcNo });            
    $.ajax({
        url: "CustomerMortgage.aspx/GetProductList",
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: Data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}

function OnSuccess(response) {            
    $('#<%=gv_productdetail.ClientID%>').DataTable(
    {
        paging: false,
        destroy: true,
        bLengthChange: true,
        lengthMenu: [[5, 10, -1], [5, 10, "All"]],
        bFilter: true,
        bSort: true,
        bPaginate: true,
        data: response.d,
        columns: [{ 'data': 'ProductId' },
            { 'data': 'ProductType' }
    });
};
```

Whole data is bind prefectly. But now I want to add button also in every column, I tried **asp:TemplateField** but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to just drop in a button.

Your markup will look like this:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv_productdetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed">
       <columns>                        
          <asp:BoundField DataField="MortageID" HeaderText="Id"  />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" />
           
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Button ID="cmdRowSel" runat="server" Text="Row Sel" />
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

       </columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

However, as a general rule I don't expose database PK "id" in the resulting grid.

And it not at all clear as to the benefits of filling this grid with a ajax call as opposed to code behind. You still had to write the web method, but to what ends? Was all that extra work worth it? You not get better performance.

but, by pulling the data from client side code, then how are you going to PREVENT the database PK id's from being hidden? You REALLY don't want the client side to see or EVER have those PK database row ID values in the browser.

A gv has a built in feature for the above problem.

(DataKeys). That means the PK row database ID can remain hidden, and NEVER exposed to the client side browser.

So say I have a list of hotels like this:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        CssClass="table table-bordered "
        DataKeyNames="ID" >
       <columns>                        
          <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel"  />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"  />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province"  />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
           
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Button ID="cmdRowSel" runat="server" Text="Row Sel" CssClass="btn"
                      OnClick="cmdRowSel_Click"/>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

       </columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

Ok, code to fill, but MORE important is the button click event.

So we have this code to fill:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()
    Dim strSQL As String =
       "SELECT ID, HotelName, City, Province, Description FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName"

    Using con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, con)

            con.Open()
            gvHotels.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
            gvHotels.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

we now have this;

[image]

And look how little code that was - super easy.

Nothing to see so far, but that button click event? I can now get the row click, and MORE important get the database PK row id, but NEVER have exposed it client side. Our row click button code behind is thus this:

```
Protected Sub cmdRowSel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.Parent.Parent

    Debug.Print("Row click index = " & gRow.RowIndex)
    Dim PkID As Integer = gvHotels.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    Debug.Print("Row click PK ID  = " & PkID)

End Sub
```

output:

```
Row click index = 5
Row click PK ID  = 72
```

Now above is very valiable, since by using DataKeys setting, then the PK row id is never required nor exposed client side.

Anyway, I just think you better off to use server side code to fill that grid. You gain ZERO performance advantage, but you lose the ability big time to get the row data with the server side events, but more important is use of the PK database row value, and not having to display it, or even allow or have the database PK row id exposed or sent to the client.

anyway, just adding the button inside a template setting as per above should work for even your setup, but that resulting button click in code behind will not have use of the database PK id unless you have that part of your client side code, and that means database ID's are now being sent to the client side, and worse your button code server side can't get at them for grids filled by ajax (unless you pull and include the PK database id's into that grid).

Comment: As per I describe in question only that asp:TemplateField is not working in it. And also why we want to see the web method as per I telling that whole data is showing perfectly it means from web method is perfect just I want to add the one button in every column which is the design part only.

Comment: As outlined, a simple drop of the asp.net button into the table would work, but to do so you need to fill the grid with server side code, since it is the server side gridview/listview that ultimate generates the standard HTML table output. So, I suppose you could write client side code that fills that table and ALSO adds the button. But, that's lots of work when none is required. I don't have a solution since I don't recommend doing that and I can't make a valid use case for spending that kind of money to do so. So drop the asp.net server control, and go with some js + client side grid setup